# Analogue of Maximum Principle in Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

Recently I saw how to show that the holomorphic functions on a compact Riemann surface are the constant functions; the proof followed rather directly from the maximum modulus principle of complex analysis.

This theorem feels related to the fact that the regular maps on an irreducible projective variety are the constants.  After all, compact Riemann surfaces are algebraic curves, so these two statements are coherent.  The way I have seen this more general fact proven is to show first that the image of a projective variety under a regular map is closed via graphs.

I'm looking for clarification on the relatedness of these two situations.  Is there an analogy of the maximum modulus principle that one can use in algebraic geometry?  Is there some kind of openness statement for morphisms in the same way one has that holomorphic maps are open? Are there any references to read about algebraic geometry over $\mathbb{C}$ approached from a complex-analytic point of view?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there is an open mapping theorem in algebraic geometry, but it is not as powerful. For one thing it is stated for the Zariski topology, and for another it does not apply to all regular maps.

Comment: Something like a maximum principle in the algebraic setting is hard to imagine; Zariski topology does not allow us to look at things like discs in $\mathbb C$; the only open sets are co-finite. However, there is a type of AG done entirely over $\mathbb C$ and with complex analytic methods in the Euclidean topology. A classic reference is Griffiths-Harris *Principles of Algebraic Geometry*, but it's also legendary for its many typos. More recent are books by Huybrechts and Voisin, but sometimes they take the "black box hard analytic arguments" approach. It's probably best to read many sources.

Comment: Great, thanks to you both!

Comment: "Are there any references to read about algebraic geometry over $\mathbb{C}$ approached from a complex-analytic point of view?" [**GAGA**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry_and_analytic_geometry#GAGA)